# ASP Parser error "not a valid identifier"

Tags: html, asp.net

I renamed an id in my site.master file from "safety_audit" to "5why_form". Now I'm getting a Parser Error Message: '5why_form' is not a valid identifier.

The offending code is:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="5why_form" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I just don't know what I've broken here. I thought the syntax for IDs was alphanumeric, and underscores. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't *start* an ASP.NET identifier (and, indeed, in many languages/frameworks (and particularly any worth their salt)) with a number. You'll need to change that to a valid identifier, removing the leading `5` makes it so.

Your identifiers are alphanumeric, and so can *contain* numbers, but can't *start* with one.